# OCaml shared variable

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I wish to create two functions : the first one generates a new integer and the second one reset the generator

```
let a = ref 0 in
    let f () = a := !a + 1 and  
    g () = a := 0; ();;
```

The REPL shows "Error: Syntax error" on the last two semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `let` also needs to be followed by an `in` (see the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html)), e.g.,

```
let inc, reset =
  let a = ref 0 in
  let f () = a := !a + 1; !a
  and g () = a := 0
  in (f, g);;
```

But maybe you want something more like this:

```
let new_counter () =
  let a = ref 0 in
  let f () = a := !a + 1; !a
  and g () = a := 0
  in (f, g);;
```

Comment: I've just tried your code but it doesn't declare f and g in global scope.
I just want to give a shared reference to multiple functions and then call them in global scope.

Comment: How's that? You probably also need a function to get at the value of `a`. Or should it also be in global scope?

Comment: Sorry ! I forgot that f is unit -> int.
     The code is `let f () = a := !a + 1; !a`

Comment: It works ! Thanks you, I think it's the good way for my problem